# Why can't tensorflow be imported?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I just installed Tensorflow, and am trying to run a [test program](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux#ValidateYourInstallation) in Python to validate the installation. When I run the program usually nothing happens. A couple times the Spyder IDE has crashed. Here is the test program:

```
print('test before')
import tensorflow as tf
print('test after')
hello = tf.constant('Hello, TensorFlow!')
sess = tf.Session()
print(sess.run(hello))
```

Interestingly, all lines before importing tensorflow run, that is "test before" is printed. However, the program seems to run into trouble with importing tensorflow because "test after" is not printed. Why can't the program successfully import tensorflow?

Also, note that the tensorflow installation seems to have been successful  because at the end it printed "Successfully installed tensorflow-1.7.0". And no errors appear when running the program. Usually if there is a problem when importing the package you get an error saying something like "[package] cannot be found". In this case the program just runs for a few seconds and then stops (or the IDE crashes) without returning an error. When running `python3 -c 'import tensorflow'` it gave the error `Illegal instruction (core dumped)`.

Tensorflow version: 1.7.0
Python version: 3.5.2
using Spyder IDE
Operating system: ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: What's the error you're getting? If it's not importing it should report an error

Comment: Try this from the command line: `python -c 'import tensorflow'`.  If this doesn't print an error then your installation isn't the problem

Comment: Did you restart your IDE/computer?

Comment: No, I am not getting any error in the Spyder IDE.

Comment: I tried running `python3 -c 'import tensorflow'`, and it gave the error `Illegal instruction (core dumped)`

Comment: And yes, I have restarted my IDE and computer. It has had no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that newer versions of TensorFlow use AVX instructions that are not supported on older CPUs. This problem was discussed in a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/17411) and in an earlier [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49094597/illegal-instruction-core-dumped-after-running-import-tensorflow). The solution was to downgrade TensorFlow to version 1.5, which I did using the following commands:

```
pip3 uninstall tensorflow
pip3 install tensorflow==1.5
```

After downgrading to 1.5 the test code worked.