# Python kernel dies when importing tensorflow 1.7

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I want to use tensorflow insinde a Jupyter notebook. However, running

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

in a Jupyter notebook immediately triggers a pop-up:

> The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically.

This issue only began after updating to tensorflow 1.7. I had not used tensorflow for a few weeks so it might also be due to an update to anaconda 5.1 with Python 3.6.

I use a Mid-2010 MacBookPro with "High Sierra 10.13.4". Removing and reinstalling anaconda 5.1 with Python 3.6, followed by installation of tensorflow (and not a single other library) via

```
pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow
```

did not resolve the issue. I do not use an isolated environment. The "anaconda3" folder is not in my home folder but directly in "Macintosh HD".

Before reinstalling anaconda, I removed it via these instructions
https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/uninstall. I also did not try to run tensorflow outside Jupyter, simply because I do not know how. But even if I did, I would still like to use Jupyter.

Comment: Not enough RAM?

Comment: 8GB. Should be more than enough to import tensorflow. And it did work before (earlier tensorflow and anaconda version).

Comment: What happens when you import in a plain old python shell?

Comment: Typing "import tensorflow as tf" into the python shell leads to
"=================== RESTART: Shell ===================" and the loss of variables.

Comment: I have not seen anything like "RESTART: Shell " on python REPL. Can you post the complete thing with details.

Comment: I do not know what "python REPL" means so let me just specify the problem. As a response to kbrose's comment, I have written a very basic Python script "demo.py" that is composed of 5 lines: 1 import tensorflow as tf; 2 import numpy as np; 3 a=np.exp(37); 4 b=5; 5 print(np.log(a)+b); Running "python demo.py" in the terminal prints "Illegal instruction: 4" into the terminal (problem). Commenting the first line in the script and running it prints "42.0" into the terminal (wonderful). When I start a Python shell and run "import tensorflow" in it, I get "RESTART: Shell"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm also running a Mid-2010 MacbookPro and have been facing the same issue. It seems the only solution is to downgrade to Tensorflow 1.5. You can do so by running the following:

```
pip3 uninstall tensorflow 
pip3 install tensorflow==1.5
```

Credit given to the solution to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49094597/illegal-instruction-core-dumped-after-running-import-tensorflow).

Comment: Thanks for posting this. Also on my Mid-2010 MacBook Pro, tensorflow version 1.5 is the last version that runs. Nevertheless it would be useful to get the most recent version (currently 1.8) running.

Comment: I had similar issue on my ubuntu machine and downgrading to version 1.5 seems to fix it for now. Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue with Tensorflow 2 '2.0.0-beta1'. I found out that when you have multiple notebooks with Tensorflow running, this problem occurs. Also, simply closing the unused notebook windows wont work, they're still running in the background, you'll have to **'Shutdown'** the notebooks

Here are the steps to shutdown a notebooks:

```
> Go to Home (of Jupyter notebook) 
> Select 'Running' tab 
> Select the unused notebooks 
> Click 'Shutdown' button
```

You will notice in the Jupyter Home that the active notebook icon is green while inactive ones are gray

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced a similar issue.
I was using python 3.7 and Tensorflow version 1.5
For we moving to Python 3.5 solve the issue.