# Illegal instruction error when require('@tensorflow/tfjs-node-gpu')

Tags: javascript, node.js, tensorflow

I'm making a server with node.js, and I'm trying to add TensorFlow.js into it. I installed with npm, both the CPU and GPU versions, but when I  include the library with require('@tensorflow/tfjs-node') or require('@tensorflow/tfjs-node-gpu'), it shows me an 'Illegal instruction' error. (Tell me if I misspelt something, I'm Spanish.)

I tried to reinstall both the CPU and GPU versions, but I don't know what to do.

This is the code I used:

```
let tf = require('@tensorflow/tfjs-node'); // The error is from this line
let argparse = require('argparse');
let express = require("express");
let app = express();
let server = app.listen(3000);
app.use(express.static("public"));
console.log("Server running!");
let socket = require("socket.io");
let io = socket(server);
io.sockets.on("connection", connectionListener);

...
```

It's supposed to show the 'Server running!' the message, but the only thing it shows is:

Instrucción ilegal (`core' generado)

Shows that because is in Spanish. In English is:

Illegal instruction (core dumped)

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49094597/illegal-instruction-core-dumped-after-running-import-tensorflow)

Comment: But that question if for the python version, not for JavaScript.

Comment: It's still the same problem; there are other reports for the JavaScript version. The code involved is compiled code that's linked to the runtime of whatever language is involved. Have you tried working on a newer computer (newer CPU/GPU)?

Comment: I'm using the newest computer I have(Intel Core Pentium Gold G5400, Asus GeForce GTX 710).

Comment: You can google for "tensorflow illegal instruction" and find plenty of information. Since some version, the code is compiled for CPUs that support the "AVX" instruction set, or something like that.

Comment: I saw that I can compile the library myself with bazel. How can I do that? And how can install it?

Comment: I have no idea; perhaps the Tensorflow project documentation has some information about doing that.