# how can I fix This issue. when I tried to import tensorflow I get an error

Tags: python

When I  import tensorflow, I get the flowing Message "Illegal instruction (core dumped)"

I am using Python 3.7.3 at ubunu 16.04 xenial

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Illegal instruction (core dumped) after running import tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49094597/illegal-instruction-core-dumped-after-running-import-tensorflow)

Comment: Did you try downgrading versions as other answers specify? ie uninstall tensorflow and reinstall an earlier version?

Comment: yes I did but I still have the  same problem