# How to install Tensorflow on Intel Xeon Processor based PC?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Not really a coding related question.
I am trying to install tensorflow on Intel Xeon(R) CPU E5620 which has Ubuntu 19.10. I can't install it with pip( could someone please explain why). It does gets installed using pip but it just says,

`illegal instruction (core dumped)`

I have tried building it from the source, but that was a pretty painful process, takes way too much time. 
My question is, is their any easier way to install tensorflow on my PC?

Comment: Do your PC have a GPU?

Comment: yes it does, I have a GeForc GTX 1050 Ti

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- For Intel Z600
- Processor: Xeon(R) CPU E5620
- OS : Ubuntu 19.10
- GPU : GTX 1050
- CUDA : 10.0
- cuDNN : 7.4
- NCCL : 2.6

with the above configuration I successfully build tensorflow 1.14 from source, NO their is no other way to get tensorflow/tensorflow-gpu on this particular PC. I have experienced this that pip and conda don't work when installing tensorflow and that building from source or using docker as mentioned on tf official [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source) is the best possible way as for 15 May 2020.

I figured that someone in near future might want to build tensorflow from source on a xeon based CPU, so I wrote how I did it step by step here, https://github.com/kazzastic/Tensorflow-BuildFromSource

Answer (score 1):

Try using conda environment. I have no problem installing and using tensorflow on my machine. I am using tensorflow 1.15 btw and as far as I recall I installed it using `pip install tensorflow-gpu==1.15`

Cpu model: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2620 v4 @ 2.10GHz

OS: Ubuntu 18.04

conda environment python version: 3.5.6

Comment: what do you mean when you say conda environment, do you simple mean use,
```conda install tensorflow-gpu=1.15``` ?

Comment: First download conda from https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html and then install it. Create an environment using 'conda create -n env_name pip python=3.x' and then activate it using 'conda activate env_name'. There you can install tensorflow either by 'pip install tensorflow-gpu==1.15'. That's what I did.It is also possible to install tensorflow with conda install, but I haven't tried.

Comment: is pip install command going to install the cuda and nvidia drivers or do I do that separately?

Comment: Nah, you have to do it yourself. Follow the instructions on Nvidia website. You also need to install cudnn for the cuda version you install. I suggest installing cuda 10.0 or 10.2. I had a hard time figuring it out. Versions of tensorflow and cuda need to be compatible.

Comment: This isn't working, I install normal tensorflow(without GPU) and when I import it it just says ```illegal instruction (core dumped)```

Comment: refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49094597/illegal-instruction-core-dumped-after-running-import-tensorflow and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49094597/illegal-instruction-core-dumped-after-running-import-tensorflow. When you do not specify version it installs the latest version which is 2.2 right now. You need to downgrade.

Comment: Thanks for all the help but this didn't work for my PC.